# How to accurately calculate Apple's EPS

Tags: stocks

I'm new to investing and as an exercise I am trying to calculate key stats from google finance for Apple (AAPL). One of the first statistics I am trying to replicate is EPS, which google finance and Scottrade have currently listed at $6.19.

My understanding is that EPS is calculated by: (Previous 4 quarters Net Income) / Current outstanding Shares. At the time of Apple's last 10-Q statement (7/23), annualized net income was $38,555M and outstanding shares was 5.989171B, resulting in EPS of $6.44.

I could be being obsessive about this but why the discrepancy? Just trying to increase my understanding here.

Answer (score 1):

On closer look, it appears that Google Finance relies on the last released 10-k statement (filing date 10/30/2013), but outstanding shares as of last 10-Q statement. Using these forms, you get ($37,037M / 5.989B ) = $6.18 EPS.

I think this is good to note, as you can manually calculate a more up to date EPS value than what the majority of investors out there are relying on.